# DataBinding exception that says system.data.datarow does not contain a property with the name

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lacking ASP.NET experience, I have been trying to resolve this issue from last 3 days without any success. DataBinding:System.Data.DataRowView does not contain with the name 'reci_seq' this is an exception I am getting when I changed my code to display gridview.

I had below code that was working perfectly fine:

```
<asp:TableCell Width="57%">
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDName" runat="server" OnClick="lnkDName_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDtag"></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>....................
```

But when I changed it to below codes I start getting the exception:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDeviceDown" runat="server" Width="100%" CellPadding="0" 
CellSpacing="1" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
          OnRowDataBound="grdDeviceDown_RowDataBound"
          OnRowDeleting="grdDeviceDown_RowDeleting" 
          OnRowCommand="grdDeviceDown_RowCommand" GridLines="None">
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="15%">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDeviceDown" Text="Device Down"></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="57%">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDName" runat="server" 
              CommandName="Modify" 
               CommandArgument='<%# Eval("reci_seq") +"," +Eval("pims_Status") %>'>
                                           <%# Eval("shortname") %> 
             </asp:LinkButton> 
         <i>(<%# Eval("pims_tag_id") %>)</i>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>..........
```

Below is how my aspx.cs code looks like:

```
protected void grdDeviceDown_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "upd")
    {
        string evntSeq = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        ViewState["DeviceDwnEvntSeq"] = evntSeq;

    }
    if (e.CommandName == "Modify")
    {
        string[] args = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
        ViewState["rdDown"] = args[0];
        ViewState["rddownPimsStatus"] = args[1];
        ViewState["PIMSTagSelection"] = "ddownupd";
        grdDeviceDown.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        OpenPimsTagSelectionPopUp();
    }

}
protected void grdDeviceDown_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
   e.Row.Cells[6].Visible = false;
   e.Row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
       int reciSeq = 0;
       string pimsStatusD = string.Empty;
       string onValD = string.Empty;
       string offValD = string.Empty;
       string onFuncD = string.Empty;
       string offFuncD = string.Empty;
       int DonVal = 0;
       int DOffVal = 0;

       DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
       pimsStatusD = dr["PIMS_STATUS"].ToString();
       reciSeq = Convert.ToInt32(dr["reci_seq"]);
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblDtag = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDtag");

       string frmSeq = dr["frrm_seq"].ToString();
       ViewState["frmSeq"] = frmSeq;


       onFuncD = dr["on_function"].ToString();
       offFuncD = dr["off_function"].ToString();
       if (onFuncD == "DS")
       {
           DonVal = Convert.ToInt32(dr["on_value_ds"].ToString());
       }
       else
       {
           DonVal = Convert.ToInt32(dr["on_value"].ToString());
       }

       if (offFuncD == "DS")
       {
           DOffVal = Convert.ToInt32(dr["off_value_ds"].ToString());
       }
       else
       {
           DOffVal = Convert.ToInt32(dr["off_value"].ToString());
       }

       if (pimsStatusD == "INACTIVE")
       {
           lblDtag.Text = "Inactive";
       }
       else
       {
           onValD = Utilities.ConvertSymbol(onFuncD);
           onValD += DonVal;
           offValD = Utilities.ConvertSymbol(offFuncD);
           offValD += DOffVal;

       }

       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblonval = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDonval");
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbloffval = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDoffval");
       lblonval.Text = onValD;
       lbloffval.Text = offValD;

       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btnModify = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnModify");
       btnModify.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript : popswitch(" + Convert.ToInt32(btnModify.CommandArgument.ToString()) + ");");
   }
```

}

Comment: Can you post the code that databinds your gridview? I see that the gridview has the `OnRowDataBound`, `OnRowDeleting`, and `OnRowCommand` events wired up, but not the `OnDataBinding` or `OnDataBound` events.

Comment: Also, a sample of the code that actually generates the data set would be helpful. I can't tell from this code what the schema of the data looks like. I can only surmise, at this point that you are not actually receiving what you think you're receiving.

Comment: Add a breakpoint to your GridView data bind, and then expand the dataset to view what the columns are at each point in your code (hover over the DataRow dr in your code and expand it once the breakpoint hits). More than likely you are getting a column name that isn't correct.